# Throttling on kafka-streams consumption, how to improve it?

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

## Context:

We have currently a stateful kafka streams application in a kubernetes environment and aws msk cluster. We are joining a total of 7 topics, creating a 13 sub-topologies topology, with 21 internal topics (excluding changelogs), and 36 stores. Each input topic have tens of millions of events (compacted topics), where we are receiving from 60 events/s to 2k events/s. Everything on 12 instances.

## Problem:

Even if we have a big cpu, a lot of memory, a performant disk or a big msk cluster, we are not able to maximize the consumption:

- we are far from 100% of cpu
- the GC is not bursting
- the disk is far from maximum use
- the msk cluster is sleeping regarding network, disk and cpu uses

When we reconsume all the topics at the same time, we are well using the maximum resources and be able to consume 100k+ events/s, use the disk at 100% iops or burst the cpu or memory of the msk cluster, but only temporary, where at 10% of the reconsumption, we are near to 30% cpu and 30% of disk iops.

When we reset the offset of a 1 partition input topic, it's obvious: we are consuming like 2k events/s where the only instance consuming this topic is sleeping (30% cpu, network at less than 1MB/s, disk at 5%) and the msk cluster also sleeping.

When we restore 1 partition only, it seems the same problems: We can see bumps every 30-40 seconds of thousand events per second consumed (and between bumps, we restore nothing), so the restore process is always very, very long.

## Configurations

Current configurations on pastebin (consumer, restore consumer, streams & rocksdb) to not pollute the message, but stack overflow don't want to accept my link... Here it is as code: `pastebin.com/Z8kcX6YG`

## What we did

We discovered that when we increase the number of streams threads from 1 to more (tested with 3 and 5 threads), we can go to 100% of disk and cpu usage during reconsumptions and restores, but still with the same issue when we are consumption big amount of events in 1 partition only: not at maximum regarding network, cpu, disk and msk cluster.

We also analysed with JFR, but it seems no throttling point, except the big amount of time spent for socket selector.

Regarding all of that, we are not able to scale properly, so each reconsumption is a pain because we need hours and days to finish the process.

## Question

How can we improve the consumption performances to be able to scale up ?